# Use owlcarousel to slide collage image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I am making a slider of several collages of images with the plugin named `owlcarousel`. The collage is displayed correctly when I have not yet reduced the screen on google chrome, opera and safari.
[image: When the screen is normal (not reduced)]

Once the screen is small, the display is completely different
[image: When the screen is reduced]

I also tested the code on firefox 37.0.2 and Internet explorer 11 when the screen is normal.

On firefox: 
[image: The display on firefox when the screen is normal]

On Internet Explorer:
[image: The display on firefox when the screen is normal (the collages do not have any margin set)]

This the code I use to realize the carousel:

```css
.featured-sellers-collage {
  width: 380px;
}

.featured-sellers-collage .div1 p {
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 float:left;
 width: 190px;
}
.featured-sellers-collage .div1 p img {
 
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-featured-sellers">
       <div class="featured-sellers-collage">
        <div class="div1">
         <p><img src="images/189x324-4.jpg" alt=""/></p>
         <p><img src="images/189x324-5.jpg" alt=""/></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="div2">
         <img src="images/380x325-6.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>

       </div>
       
       <div class="featured-sellers-collage">
        <div class="div1">
         <p><img src="images/189x324-4.jpg" alt=""/></p>
         <p><img src="images/189x324-5.jpg" alt=""/></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="div2">
         <img src="images/380x325-6.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="featured-sellers-collage">
        <div class="div1">
         <p><img src="images/189x324-4.jpg" alt=""/></p>
         <p><img src="images/189x324-5.jpg" alt=""/></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="div2">
         <img src="images/380x325-6.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="featured-sellers-collage">
        <div class="div1">
         <p><img src="images/189x324-4.jpg" alt=""/></p>
         <p><img src="images/189x324-5.jpg" alt=""/></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="div2">
         <img src="images/380x325-6.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="featured-sellers-collage">
        <div class="div1">
         <p><img src="images/189x324-4.jpg" alt=""/></p>
         <p><img src="images/189x324-5.jpg" alt=""/></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="div2">
         <img src="images/380x325-6.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="featured-sellers-collage">
        <div class="div1">
         <p><img src="images/189x324-4.jpg" alt=""/></p>
         <p><img src="images/189x324-5.jpg" alt=""/></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="div2">
         <img src="images/380x325-6.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="featured-sellers-collage">
        <div class="div1">
         <p><img src="images/189x324-4.jpg" alt=""/></p>
         <p><img src="images/189x324-5.jpg" alt=""/></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="div2">
         <img src="images/380x325-6.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>
       </div>
       
      </div>
     </div>
     <script src="js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
     <script>
      (function($){
    
       $('.carousel-featured-sellers').owlCarousel({
        items: 3,
        loop:true,
        margin:25,
        nav:true,
        navText: ["<span class='carousel-nav-left'><i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i></span>","<span class='carousel-nav-right'><i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i></span>"],
        dots: true,
        responsive:{
         0:{
          items:1
         },
         430:{
          items:2
         },
         800:{
          items:3
         },
         1400:{
          items:4
         },
         1800:{
          items:6
         },
         2400:{
          items:7
         },
         3000:{
          items:9
         }
        }
       })
       
      })(jQuery);
     </script>
```

Kindly let me know how I can solve that problem. Thanks

Comment: this might be happening of your image width.Dotn't add fix width to image. make the images responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `float: right;` to the `div2` of your code will solve the problem on firefox and internet explorer.

Now concerning the responsiveness issue is due to the fix width, better use percentage.

Try this code:

```css
body {
 width: 380px;
}
.featured-sellers-collage {
  width: 100%;
}

.featured-sellers-collage .div1 p {
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 float:left;
 width: 50%;
}
.featured-sellers-collage .div1 p img {
 
 width: 100%;
}
.featured-sellers-collage .div2 {
 flaot: right;
}
```